# do i use trig substitution or use the arccosh rule for this question?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I just wanted to ask which of the following integral are  right 
 $$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{25x^2-4}}}=\frac{1}{5}\ln \left( \frac{5x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{25x^2-4}}{2} \right)+C$$

or

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{25x^2-4}}}=\frac{1}{5}\cosh^{-1}\frac{5x}{2}$$

or is it both?

Comment: Did you try to graph both?

Comment: Something looks off about these, I think you might be off by a factor of 5 or 1/5

Comment: just edited it.

Comment: Differentiate the expressions to check. It will be good practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you note that $\cosh^{-1}x=\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})$, they are the same.

Comment: thank you. I was not aware of that rule.

Comment: You can derive it by using the quadratic formula on the definition of $\cosh$

Comment: Or $\cosh \ln a = (a+1/a)/2$.